# Culinary uses for juniper extract?

Tags: culinary-uses, fruit

I bought some juniper extract for making bath stuff, and it doesn't seem to be very effective for this purpose. I have used juniper berries before, so I thought I might be able to use the extract for cooking or baking. I have not been able to find any recipes online.

Is juniper extract ok to eat? What types of applications would it be good for, I assume whole berries is much better choice for marinades. Would it have the same uses as orange or peppermint extract?

Comment: Do you know if it is 'food-grade' oil? If it isn't you shouldn't eat it as it may contain stabilisers which are not edible.

Comment: I can check when I get home, I am pretty sure it is, and is probably why the bath stuff didn't turn out. Most sites that come up suggest taking a certain number of drops internally as a remedy but I'm not interested in doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with nixy. Make sure it's food grade. If it's not the extract may have other stabilizers that you don't want to consume. Glycerin is an example where glycerin that you use in soap is different from the food grade glycerin one would use to make non-alcoholic vanilla extract.

Comment: it is food grade, the bottle reccomends adding a certain amount to water to drink as a supplement.

Comment: I'm not familiar with cooking with juniper but juniper is commonly used with game and meats. Dilute with water as the instructions recommend then using that as a marinade ingredient sounds like it would a safe and appropriate use.

Answer (score 0):

You could make gin! Add the juniper to vodka and you have instant gin. BTW, I don't drink alcohol.

Comment: Also, juniper extract could be used in any food recipe that calls for gin. Gin is a natural with cabbage.